# Why when using setState(...) is the console.log null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, console.log, global-state

Why when I console.log(data) is does it log the data but when I try and log the item set by set state its null? I don't understand is it because it doesn't have time to update before console logging?

```
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);
        const [pending, setpending] = useState(true);
        const [userData, setuserData] = useState({});

        useEffect(() => {
            Authentication.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                setCurrentUser(user)
                setpending(false)
                localStorage.setItem('user', user.uid);
                console.log(localStorage.getItem('user'));
            });

            getData()

        }, []);

        const getData = () => {
            Authentication.firestore().collection('Health_data')
                .doc(localStorage.getItem('user'))
                .get()
                .then(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(data));
                    setuserData(data)
                    console.log(data)
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error reading health", error);
                });
                console.log(userData)
        }
```

Comment: You are talking about `userData` ?

Comment: yes console.log(data) reproduces the data form my database

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume you're confused by the output of `console.log(userData);` at the end of `getData`. There are two reasons why it doesn't show the updated user, either of which would be enough on its own. :-) They are:

1. The `console.log(userData)` happens **before** the `setuserData` call, because promise callbacks are always asynchronous.
2. `userData` is a constant within the `Example` function call, its value will not change. When the state is changed, `Example` will get called again, and *that* **new** `userData` constant will have the updated user in it. (Note that it doesn't matter whether it's declared with `let` or `const`, it's effectively a constant either way.) Each of those constants exists in an *execution context* that's tied to the specific call to `Example` the constant was created in. More in Dan Abramov's article [*A Complete Guide to `useEffect`*](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) (which is about much more than `useEffect`).

Here's a demonstration:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

let executionContext = 0;
const Example = () => {
    const contextNumber = ++executionContext;
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);

    const log = msg => console.log(`[${contextNumber}]: ${msg}`);

    log(`Example called, value = ${value}`);
    
    const onClick = () => {
        log(`onClick`);
        delay(800)
        .then(() => {
            const newValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
            log(`calling setValue(${newValue})...`);
            setValue(newValue);
            log(`value is still ${value} (reason #2)`);
        });
        log(`value is still ${value} (reason #1)`);
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
            {value}
            <div>
                <input type="button" onClick={onClick} value="Click Me" />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: the first point is probably the reason because in the react plugin I can see userData changing, but can't seem to get it to print in any of my files

Comment: I can see this in the react component plugin https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: @lukeet - As I said, it's both. I've beefed up the explanation of #2 a bit and added a demonstration. (BTW, that link doesn't work.)

Comment: https://imgur.com/7cl1gJ7 does this work as you can see the data with userData does change and is updated I don't quite understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: @lukeet - Did you read the updated answer and look at the demonstration? The `userData` constant within a given execution context can't change. But your function is called again, which creates a new execution context, with a new constant in it. But the *old* one may still be referenced by closures within the original execution context. That's why two reasons. :-)

Comment: Trying to wrap my head around that hahaha thanks for the update and the code snippet

Comment: @lukeet - You're welcome! Hope it helps. Dan Abramov's article is really useful for understanding this stuff. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about this code:

```
Authentication.firestore().collection('Health_data')
                .doc(localStorage.getItem('user'))
                .get()
                .then(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    localStorage.setItem('user_data', JSON.stringify(data));
                    setuserData(data)
                    console.log(data)
                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.error("Error reading health", error);
                });
                console.log(userData)
```

The problem is

```
Authentication.firestore().collection('Health_data')
                .doc(localStorage.getItem('user'))
                .get()
```

Is async execution, so `console.log(userData)`, sometimes will execute before the `Authentication` call and the value will be `null`.

So you need to ensure that the `Authentication` call has finished

Comment: This sounds like a good solution how do I do this? because in the components react extension I see the string i want to reproduce https://imgur.com/undefined

Comment: Hey the image is 404 :(
Maybe isn't a good idea print `userData`, I suppose you want to show things based on this, try to use in the jsx, like this:


`return <div> { userData && <div> here you will able to user the userData</div>} </div>`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/voixpQJ is that better just wanted to show that the console log data was being printed. That's not a bad idea of printing a div.

Comment: Yes, you could do something like this: 

`{ userData && <div>user age {userData.age}</div>}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(userData !== null) {
    console.log(userData)
}
```

this code seems to work for me but I'm not sure how I can use this to access the information on other pages the same way?